# Pandas DataFrame from MultiIndex and NumPy structured array (recarray)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

First I create a two-level [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('X','Y'), ('a','b')])
```

I can use it like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,4)), columns=ind)
```

Which gives:

```
     X         Y     
     a    b    a    b
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

But now I'm trying to do this:

```
dtype = [('Xa','f8'), ('Xb','i4'), ('Ya','f8'), ('Yb','i4')]
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(3, dtype), columns=ind)
```

But that gives:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(X, a), (X, b), (Y, a), (Y, b)]
Index: []
```

I expected something like the previous result, with three rows.

Perhaps more generally, what I want to do is to generate a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex columns where the columns have distinct types (as in the example, `a` is float but `b` is int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug, and worth reporting [as an issue github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

A workaround is to set the columns manually after construction:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(3, dtype))

In [12]: df1.columns = ind

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
     X       Y
     a  b    a  b
0  0.0  0  0.0  0
1  0.0  0  0.0  0
2  0.0  0  0.0  0
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have reported it as a bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13415 and your workaround is indeed effective.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(3, dtype), columns=ind)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(X, a), (X, b), (Y, a), (Y, b)]
Index: []
```

is just showing the textual representation of the dataframe output.

```
Columns: [(X, a), (X, b), (Y, a), (Y, b)]
```

is then just the text representation of the index.

if you instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(3, dtype), columns=ind)

print type(df.columns)

<class 'pandas.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'>
```

You see it is indeed a `pd.MultiIndex`

That said and out of the way.  What I don't understand is why specifying the index in the dataframe constructor removes the values.

A work around is this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(3, dtype))

df.columns = ind

print df

     X       Y   
     a  b    a  b
0  0.0  0  0.0  0
1  0.0  0  0.0  0
2  0.0  0  0.0  0
```